Return products that contain string clicked
I'm trying to practice React by building a kind of ecommerce template and I'm currently experimenting with filtering products that contain the word/string clicked in a filter section.
I've created the below which pulls in all products from a json into a product array and then pulls in all the available categories and brands into a filter section:

I'm trying to make it so it updates the product feed to only show products that have a brand that matches the brand name/string clicked in the filters (example: clicking Essence would only show that one Essence brand product and not show the Glamour Beauty product)
I thought this would work but it just seems to remove all products so obviously I've got it wrong:
const [products, setProducts] = useState(props.productData.products)
const [productsLimit, setProductsLimit] = useState(props.productData.limit)  

clickFilter = document.querySelectorAll('.filter .name');

clickFilter.forEach(cF => {
  cF.addEventListener('click', (f) => {
    f = f.target.textContent;
    console.log(f);
    setProducts(
      products.filter(product => product.brand == f)
    )
  });
});


<div className='products'>

  {/* checks the product data exists before mapping it */}
  {products?.slice(0, productsLimit).map(product => (
    <div className='product' key={product.id}>
      <div className='productImage'>
        <img src="" data-src={product.thumbnail} />
        </div>
      <div className='productInfo'>
        <div className='productTitle'>
          <div className='productBrand'>{product.brand}</div> 
          <div className='productName'>{product.title}</div>
        </div>
        <div className='productPrice'>Price: {product.price}</div>
      </div>

    </div>
  ))}
</div>  

So help understanding what I'm doing wrong and how to get it working would be much appreciated thanks.

If you want you can simplify this by having a state hover the brands names and filter all your product on the render !
in quick code

const brands = ['brandA', 'brandB', 'brandC'];

function DisplayProducts(props: { products: { id: number; brand: string, name: string }[] }) {
    const [filters, setFilters] = useState<string[]>([]);

    const filteredProducts = props.products.filter(
        (product) => filters.length === 0 ? product : filters.includes(product.brand),
    );

    return (
        <>
            {brands.map((brand) => (
                <button
                    key={brand}
                    onClick={() =>
                        setFilters((prev) => {
                            if (prev.includes(brand)) return prev.filter((filter) => brand.localeCompare(filter));
                            return prev.concat(brand);
                        })
                    }
                >
                    {brand}
                </button>
            ))}
            {filteredProducts.map((product) => (
                <div key={product.id}>product.name</div>
            ))}
        </>
    );
}

To be more precise, when you click on a filter, it will add or remove it from the array of filters and so trigger a new render (or reconciliation in this case).
During the new render the variable filteredProducts will be recalculated with the new set of filters.
If you are learning react right I highly recommend to read this part of the react doc react docs . Don't worry it's not a traditional doc, but some explanation on how to develop in react.
Now to understand with your code what is going wrong I will need a little bit more detail on how you implemented the filter on the left side.
